# Screen sharing using java, gives zoomed content

Tags: java, reactjs, swing, awt

I am trying to write an application, where I am capturing a screen shot using the below code,

```
 public String captureImage() {
    String payload = null;
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream outstream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Robot robotObject = new Robot();
        BufferedImage img = robotObject
                .createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
        ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outstream);
        outstream.flush();
        byte[] imageInByte = outstream.toByteArray();
        payload = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(imageInByte);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return payload;
}
```

This method returns the encoded image, but its zoomed, the received need to change the resolution to view the actual page, any suggestion to optimize.

Retrieval mechanism:

```
 <img id="elementId" src={`data:image/png;base64,${this.state.image}`} />
```

I am using react js to retrieve and display result. In the above statement, `image` is the variable which holds the string value returned from the DB

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. I for one have no idea how the code will be used. I don't know why you are using a String for an Image.

Comment: @camickr This string is sent as an input, to a DB which serves as a middle ware. There are multiple consumers. sending the entire image to the DB, was throwing a non-serializable exception.

Comment: The receiver receives the string, decodes the string and renders

Comment: As I said post a demo. After you create the String decoded it and display the image on a JLabel of your frame to that we can see the behaviour. The idea is to first get the code working on your machine and then worry about the middleware. This might help isolate which step is causing the problem. Also believe you can store an image directly in a database, so there may be no need to encode it to a to String.

Comment: Added the code to retrieve the response